# Time-series boxplot in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, boxplot

How can I create a boxplot for a pandas time-series where I have a box for each day?

Sample dataset of hourly data where one box should consist of 24 values:

```
import pandas as pd
n = 480
ts = pd.Series(randn(n),
               index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01",
                                   periods=n,
                                   freq="H"))
ts.plot()
```

I am aware that I could make an extra column for the day, but I would like to have proper x-axis labeling and x-limit functionality (like in `ts.plot()`), so being able to work with the datetime index would be great.

There is a similar question for R/ggplot2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389553/how-to-make-a-timeseries-boxplot-in-r), if it helps to clarify what I want.

Comment: There is a possibly nicer solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194581/best-way-to-generate-day-of-week-boxplots-from-a-pandas-timeseries) which uses only Pandas, its `.boxplot()` and `.pivot()` functions and does not require Seaborn

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If its an option for you, i would recommend using [Seaborn](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/), which is a wrapper for Matplotlib. You could do it yourself by looping over the groups from your timeseries, but that's much more work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 480
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=n, freq="H"))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
seaborn.boxplot(ts.index.dayofyear, ts, ax=ax)
```

Which gives:
[image]

Note that i'm passing the `day of year` as the `grouper` to seaborn, if your data spans multiple years this wouldn't work. You could then consider something like:

```
ts.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

Edit, for 3-hourly you could use this as a grouper, but it only works if there are no minutes or lower defined. :

```
[(dt - datetime.timedelta(hours=int(dt.hour % 3))).strftime('%Y%m%d%H') for dt in ts.index]
```

Comment: I actually do use seaborn anyway, so that's definitely an option. Thanks! /edit: Is there any way to use this for arbitrary times, e.g. 3-hour boxplots, 7 day boxplots, etc.?

Comment: Yes, you can pas anything to Seaborns grouper. The challenge is to define the groups from the index of the Series. I have added an example for 3-hourly periods. Something like that could work for arbitrary periods of time. Its not very readable unfortunately, perhaps some simplification is possible by using Pandas `Timegrouper`. Opening a specific question on Seaborns grouper might get you some help from people who use Seaborn a lot, which i'm not.

Answer (score 11):

*(Not enough rep to comment on accepted solution, so adding an answer instead.)*

The accepted code has two small errors: (1) need to add `numpy` import and (2) nned to swap the `x` and `y` parameters in the `boxplot` statement. The following produces the plot shown.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 480
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=n, freq="H"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
seaborn.boxplot(ts.index.dayofyear, ts, ax=ax)
```

Comment: You're the best!

Answer (score 2):

It only uses native pandas and allows for hierarchical date-time grouping (i.e spanning years). The key is that if you pass a function to `groupby()`, it will be called on each element of the dataframe's index. If your index is a `DatetimeIndex` (or similar), you can access all of the dt's convenience functions for resampling!

```
n = 480
ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(n), index=pd.date_range(start="2014-02-01", periods=n, freq="H"))
ts.groupby(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")).boxplot(subplots=False, figsize=(12,9), rot=90)
```

[image]

Comment: add plt.show() in code above to get the figure. also import matplotlib.pyplot as plt.