# Boxplot for tuple groupby throws VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences

Tags: python, time-series, pandas-groupby, boxplot

I have timeseries with a ***'parameter'*** value among other columns. I would like to **boxplot** this across both year AND month. Dataframe is a log, and 'datestamp_col' is not unique, and can not be used as an index (some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507404/time-series-boxplot-in-pandas) [online](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/time-series-analysis-python/) use unique Datetime as an index with simpler syntax).
This works just fine (box plots are created) separately with groupby generating

```
df[flt][['parameter']].groupby(by=[df['datestamp_col'].dt.year]).groups:
{2014.0: [72, 92, 94,
```

works fine with the boxplot (month or year grouping each work separately):

```
df[flt][['parameter']].groupby(by=[df['datestamp_col'].dt.year]).boxplot(
                            subplots=False, 
                            column='parameter', ...
```

Attempts to get a more granular picture with box plots for months AND years appear to generate correct groups:

```
df[flt][['parameter']].groupby(by=[df[flt]['datestamp_col'].dt.year, df[flt]['datestamp_col'].dt.month]).groups

{(2014, 9): [45, 72, 88, 92,  - September 2014 values to generate boxplot
```

However attempts to create a boxplot for each month of each year results in an error:

```
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
```

The question is where / how do I specify 'dtype=object' in my syntax to get a few more box plots I want, or to be more technical convert index to a string/object inside groupby ?!
Thank you

PS flt - is another filter, and list is used or [['parameter']] just as a legacy to be able to add more columns.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, all I had to do was to remove

```
column='parameter',
```

from inside boxplot syntax. It was kind of redundant being a single column anyway ...